# Восстановить верхнюю панель

Tags: ubuntu

как восстановить верхнюю панель убунту 12.04

Comment: Сам-то Kubuntu юзаю, но обсуждалось это [**здесь**](http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=186201.0)

Answer (score 1):

Наводим курсор на *верхнюю панель* и делаем <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Правый клик</kbd>.
Из выпавшего меню выбираем нужные пункты.

Это работает только в Gnome, в Unity нет такой функции.

Comment: спасибо,помогло.